# Optimized way to get to every file / folder in my dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, recursion

I thought I had it all figured out - "Yes! Finally, I succeeded using recursive functions - yeaah.. oh oh nope"

I have a dictionary containing data on a file structure with folders and files:

```
{
    "FOLDER_NAME": {
        type: "dir",
        children: {
                    "FOLDER_NAME": {
                        type: "dir", 
                        children: { ... }
                    },
                    "FILE_NAME": {
                        type: "file",
                        url: '...'
                    },
                    "FILE_NAME": {
                        type: "file",
                        url: '...'
                    }
    }
}
```

I wrote the following recursive function to get to any element, whenever it's a dir, I want to process all the contents of that dir, whenever there is a dir in the dir, I want to process that dir first, and so on. 
The initial call to `process_dir` is made with `dir_name="/root/path"`, `dir_content` is the snippet above and `first = True`.

```
def process_dir(dir_name, dir_content, first):
    global download_path
    if first:
        download_path = dir_name + '/'
    else:
        download_path += clean_path(dir_name) + '/'
    full_path = download_path
    if not os.path.exists(full_path):
        os.makedirs(full_path)
    for x in dir_content:
        type = dir_content[x]['type']
        if type == 'dir':
            process_dir(x, dir_content[x]['children'], False)
        elif type == 'file':
            download_file(x, dir_content[x]['size'], dir_content[x]['url'])
```

Should this work as expected? It's not working as expected for me at least, because it's not going over every node that is in the dictionary sequentially.
How can I detect that after processing the contents of a certain dir and it returns to the original call to `process_dir` that dir so that I can remove the last subdir part from `full_path`?

---

With the help of Javeed's answer I was able to fix my problems resulting in the following modified code snippet:

```
def process_dir(path, new_name, dir_content):
    if not dir_content:
        return None
    new_path = path + '/' + new_name
    if not os.path.exists(new_path):
        os.makedirs(new_path)
    for x in dir_content:
        type = dir_content[x]['type']
        if type == 'dir':
            process_dir(new_path, clean_path(x), dir_content[x]['children'])
        elif type == 'file':
            download_file(new_path + '/' + clean_path(x), dir_content[x]['size'], dir_content[x]['url'])
```

Comment: "Should this work as expected?" It's easier if you tell us if it does or doesn't for you. A few general tips though: you should be able to avoid the `global download_path`, and use `os.path.join` to concatenate parts of the path name. You can do both at the same time by calling `process_dir(os.path.join(dir_name, x), ...)` (and then you can probably also leave out the `first` argument).

Comment: @Evert The `first` argument has to do with the initial call, because my `clean_path` function will strip out the divisor and should only be called per single dir or file name. I can get rid of the global `download_path` yes, thx.

Comment: `os.path.join` doesn't care about the path separator, so there's no need to manually remove that and add it again. For example `os.path.join('/home', 'evert', 'Documents/', 'somefile.txt')` results in `'/home/evert/Documents/somefile.txt'`: no need to manually remove or append '/'s. In fact, if you like to platform compatible, `os.path.join` will take of the differences in path separators (such as `\\` on Windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some nasty no-nos in this one:

```
global download_path
```

Please for your own sanity always avoid using a global with recursion. The idea behind recursion is that stuff is operated on bottom up or something along those lines. If you are reading a global, okay cool whatever that works just fine, but if you modify ANYTHING outside the recursion's call stack, it can be a mess. Learn workarounds to this, such as passing values in (which looks like it would work here).

Also, you have no exit condition. What happens when you reach elements which have no children or entries? While sometimes the structure of a recursive function can inherently permit it to exit when done without an explicit exit condition, its considered very bad form to exclude it. Something like

```
if not dir_content: return None
```

or whatnot will make it easy to read.

As to whether or not this works, depends on what download_file and clean_path are doing, but I won't comment on specifics. Instead, I will say, in answer to your last question, that you shouldn't NEED to detect when it has finished processing the contents of a subdirectory in order to alter the global path, there shouldn't even be a global path.

Try passing, as another parameter, the path you want to add on too. This insures that any recursive child call will always have the same base directory from the parent. No modification needed.

Here's a few other tips on recursion since you mentioned you are new to it:

1. Plan out your recursion in an abstract way. Ask the big three questions: 1. What do I need in every single frame to do the intended function? 2. How will I know when I am done? 3. What do I want to get back?
2. Use a base function for the recursion, by which I mean, a starting function that preps up the information used to start the recursion. Where you have that parameter called first, instead just make a function that gets called once which sets up the base path and then starts the recursion with that as input. Recursive functions should not be expected to maintain contextual awareness.

Comment: I am working on your suggestions. Meanwhile I can tell you that `clean_path` is only turning the directory or file name into a sanitised version. `download_file` is getting the downloading the file based on the url value to the `/path/through/dirs/filename` location, but not returning anyting to the recursive function.